# Can't see achievement in google play games

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm working on a game which has been published to google play. Now we want to add achievement service to this game.

Following [google play service samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples), everything works fine. I can sign in and unlock the achievement successfully.

But the only thing trouble me is that I can't see the achievements in my device.

First I think it may be because the cache, but after two day, I still can't see it.

The game service's state is `ready to test`, but I heard from someone else, it is no mater.

So I don't know what I had missed.

Any suggestion is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user you are logged in as a "testing user"? If the achievement is not yet published, only [testers](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub) will be able to see the achievement.

Comment: Yes, I use a test user to log in.